# Gnuplot, yerrorbar, text as x axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following data:

```
t4.8k   1.84    1.86    1.83
t5.8k   1.82    1.84    1.8
t7.10k  1.79    1.8     1.77 
t8.8k   1.8     1.84    1.76
```

I need to plot this in GNU plot using yerror bars.
Column1 - dataset name.  This is the xaxis scale.
Column2 - Y-Mean
Column3 - Y-Max
Column4 - Y-Min

Here is the plotting code that I use:

```
plot "chameleonConfidence.dat" using xtic(1):2:4:3  title "Ratio of Time Taken" with yerrorbars
```

But this gives me the following error

> Warning: empty x range [4.94066e-324:4.94066e-324], adjusting to [4.94066e-324:4.94066e-324]
>   "chameleonConfidence.gplot", line 15: x_min should not equal x_max!

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
set xrange [-1:4]
TITLE="Ratio of Time Taken"
plot "chameleonConfidence.dat" using ($0):2:4:3:xticlabels(1) with yerrorbars title TITLE
```

the `xtic` function doesn't replace the x-values in your file -- it is an automagic extra field you can add to the using specification to add the xticlabels on your axis.  Basically, you just need the line number (`$0`) to be the x value and then you are all set (moving `xtic(1)` to the end of your using spec)